# Visual Studio 2017 Can't deploy to Xbox One

Tags: deployment, uwp, visual-studio-2017, xbox, xbox-one

I am new to developing apps for the Xbox one. I have been following the tutorial as listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/getting-started). However, I the publish keeps failing due to the following:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '169.xxx.xxx.xx' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274C) [0x8007274C] Test

I have just installed the latest SDK from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), but I did not install the packages for C++.

Also, using the IP address and port I cannot connect via the web browser, and my router doesn't show my Xbox either.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to click the Launch Home button. Then go to settings and configure your WiFi network. After that is done, then restart your console. Your IP address should be updated, and showing on the router.